# Calculating the flux over a non simply connected surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, geometric-topology, stokes-theorem, curl

Here is the question:

> The surface $S$ shown here has boundary the circle of radius $2$ in the $xz$-plane. With respect to the normal vector field indicated, compute the flux of $G = \langle 0, 3, 0 \rangle$ through $S$.

[image: Surface S with normal vector field n]

Based on the divergence theorem, since $\nabla\cdot G = 0$, I assume that the flux would also be $0$. However, I'm not sure whether the divergence theorem applies for such surfaces that seem to have holes in them. I also don't know what it means when the question says "with respect to the normal vector field indicated." I see that the vector $n$ is labeled in the diagram, but I have no idea how to use that information. Any help or clarification on this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue with applying the divergence theorem is that the surface has an opening on the $x$-$z$ plane.

Comment: so how would you suggest i go about solving this problem?

Comment: *Hint:* Cap off the surface with a disk $D$ such that $S \cup D$ is a closed surface. Then apply the divergence theorem and solve for flux through $S$.

Comment: What do I do about the hole in the middle of S? Or is that not even a hole?

Comment: The "hole" in the middle is not really a "hole" (topologists would call it a "handle") and it does not affect applicability of the formula.

Comment: I still don't get how I solve the problem. Sure I can put a disc at the bottom to close the surface, but I still don't see how I can go about finding the flux. Div G is still 0, so based on the divergence theorem the flux would still be zero.